# How to add dynamic array index value in angular html page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular I want to add dynamic array index value in html page. I tried different solution I am not getting a solutions. I am not getting any error as well.

I have create a array in typescript as shown below

my typescript

```
months : string[] = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
```

the above array I want to pass dynamic index value in html page. I tried but I am not getting the value.

I tried like this `{{  months[ result.startDate.split('/')[1]  ]  }}` . If i type static index value it is working.

html page

```
 <div class="row" style="width: 110%;" *ngFor="let result of allEvents">

              <p class="start-date" >{{ result.startDate.split('/')[0]  }} </p> <br><p  >{{  months[ result.startDate.split('/')[1]  ]  }} </p>

        </div>
```

result object I am getting

```
0:
_id: "5e8b033bd3d04a24db92288a"
name: "Casting call for kannada movie"
description: "Looking for:↵Female artist Age: 17-26↵Kids Age :4-12"
startTime: "6"
endTime: "21"
startDate: "04/04/2020"
endDate: "31/05/2020"
participant: []
userId: "5e536de00d691f6427bcaec1"
pageId: {profileImage: {…}, coverPage: {…}, isBlocked: false, softDelete: false, isVerified: true, …}
createdAt: "2020-04-06T10:23:55.874Z"
updatedAt: "2020-04-06T10:23:55.874Z"
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Show `result` object

Comment: @sigmato, Please console `result.startDate.split('/')[1]` and see the output

Comment: @AdritaSharma I have pasted the object

Comment: @AlokMali If i display only ```result.startDate.split('/')[1] ``` I am getting value as 04

Comment: @sigmato What is your expected output? For `startDate: "04/04/2020"`, what do you want to display in template?

Comment: @AdritaSharma instead of month number I want to display full  month from that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That why it is not working. You need to remove `0` from `04` before putting value in the `month` array.

Parse your index with `parseInt` before passing it in the `month` array.

Please see the example below. It is in core JS.

Let me know, If you want it in an angular format I will create a `stackblitz` example for you

```js
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var result = {};
result.startDate = "04/04/2020";
var key = parseInt(result.startDate.split('/')[1]);
console.log(months[key]);
```

Please check this link for an example in angular - [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzan7j)

Comment: I tried but it is not working. Can u make me a angular format. it will be hepfull

Comment: if I display like this ```{{  months[ (04) ]  }}``` it is working fine. but not dynamic

Comment: Please wait, I am creating an example in angular. I will share a link in a moment.

Comment: @sigmato, I have added a link to example please check it.

Comment: thank you very very much for helping bro now its working. I was trying this from yeserday. Finally solved thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

.html

```
<p class="start-date" > </p> <br><p>{{getMonthName(result.startDate) }} </p>
```

.ts

```
getMonthName(month) {
  return this.months[(parseInt(month.split("/")[1])-1)];
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7xxsw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: You are welcome. Do add `-1`, else you will get May for 04 which should be april (Array starts with 0 :D)

Answer (score 0):

**component.html**

```
 <div> {{getMonthName(result.startDate) }} </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
getMonthName(date) {
    return this.months[(new Date(date).getMonth())]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is transfor your object so, startDate and endDate becomes Date

```
allEvents.forEach(x=>{
   x.startDate=new Date(x.startDate)
   x.endDate =new Date(x.endDate )
})
```

And use pipeDate

```
{{result.startDate| date:'MMM'}}
```